# QuickSort метод медианы из трех

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Улучшаю квиксорт методом медианы из трех. Сначала я находил медиану таким образом: в массив из трех элементов положил левый, средний и правый элементы последовательности, отсортировал этот массив вставками, и выбрал средний элемент. Но это очень неоптимальный алгоритм. Теперь ищу медиану при помощи условий:

```
/*Процедура Partition, модифицированная методом медианы из трех*/
int MedianPartition(int *a, int p, int r){
    int left, mid, right, mediana;

    left = p;
    mid = (p + r) / 2;
    right = r;

    if(left > mid){
        if(left < right){
            mediana = left;
        }else mediana = right;
    }else if(mid > right){
        mediana = right;
    }else mediana = mid;

    std::swap(mediana, a[r]);
    return partition(a, p, r);
}
```

Я запутался к логике вычислений медианы, она, мне кажется, даже сложнее, чем сам квиксорт. Что я делаю не так? Вот пример неправильной работы этого алгоритма. https://ideone.com/QuNjjd

**Дополнение**. Написал вот такую функцию вычисления медианы. https://ideone.com/WLqc5R
Видно, что работает она как-то странно, а если использовать такой способ нахождения медианы в процедуре Partition, то сортировка зацикливается.

**Дополнение 2**. Как я только не мучил эту функцию за последние 1.5 часа. Вот последний вариант, и он тоже не работает. https://ideone.com/7VuMdd 
А перед этим было жуткое нагромождение тернарных операторов.

Comment: То есть, нужно с трех элементов найти "средний"? В любом случае, что бы отсортировать три элемента нужно сделать три сравнения (в некоторых случаях будет достаточно двух).

Очень похоже, что Вы как раз пытаетесь изобрести сортировку быстрее.

Квиксорт многие пытались улучшить, но он стает быстрее только на определенных, специально подготовленных данных.

Comment: Это часть задумки. У меня есть очень быстрая реализация квиксорта на стеке отложенных заданий, в ней опорным элементом берется случайный. Я хочу добавить в реализацию квиксорта на стеке метод медианы из трех и посмотреть, какая будет скорость. Кстати, вот тут я опечатался: не std::swap(mediana, a[r]);, а std::swap(a[mediana], a[r]);

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо найти медиану из *значений* `a[l]`, `a[(l + r) / 2]`, `a[r]` (причем, `r` это индекс последнего элемента в сортируемом отрезке), а Вы зачем-то ищете медиану *среди индексов* (и мне кажется, что неправильно), а не значений.

Кстати, сама медиана 3-х значений IMHO вычисляется так

```
int med (int a, int b, int c)
{
  if (a > b) { // ba ?c
    if (c > a) // bac
      return a;
    return (b > c) ? b : c;
  } 
  // ab ? c
  if (c > b) // abc
    return b;
  return (a > c) ? a : c;
}
```

Естественно, в Вашем случае надо передавать массив и индексы, сравнивать элементы массива и возвращать индекс медианного элемента.